# python - Concatenate strings inside pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, concatenation

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '1',  1: '2',  2: '4',  3: '7',  4: '7'},
 'B': {0: 'S', 1: 'S', 2: 'D', 3: 'D', 4: 'S'},
 'C': {0: 'XX',  1: 'WX',  2: 'WX',  3: 'XX',  4: 'XW'},
 'Location': {0: '32',  1: '63',  2: '32',  3: '42',  4: '42'}})
```

[image]

And I created this function:

```
def Transformation(df_, col_names):
    # function code (irrelevant for the problem statement)
    df_.groupby([col_names,"Location"]) # the line problem
    # function code (irrelevant for the problem statement)
    return df_ # (irrelevant for the problem statement)

Transformation(z, ["A", "B"]) # How you call the function. col_names has to be more than 1.
```

`# the line problem` above: How can I concatenate `col_names` with `"Location"` **in the groupby argument**? You can assume that `dimensions` is always given as a list of strings with more of one element, just like this:

```
Transformation(df, ["A", "B"])
Transformation(df, ["C", "A"])
Transformation(df, ["A", "B", "C", "D"]) # You can assume that the whole abecedary is in the columns of `df` and you can combine them as you wish, but for minimal example purposes I think two is enough
```

`"Location"` cannot go inside the `dimensions` arguments (for the function purposes), if you do so the function will raise an error. So, assume that `"Location"` never goes in the input arguments but rather it's added somewhere in the function code, and when I'm adding `"Location"` is where I'm having the problem.

One of the approaches I used and I don't understand why is not working:

```
df_.groupby(col_names.append("Location"))
```

Which led me to:

```
x = ["A","B", "C"]
x_aux = x.append("Location")
x_aux # gives "None"
```

BUT!:

```
x = ["A","B", "C"]
x.append("Location")
x # gives ["A","B", "C", "Location"]
```

Why does that happen? Any suggestions to concatenate it **inside the groupby** function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put Location in a list and use "+" to concat the lists.

```
df_.groupby(col_names+["Location"])
```

Comment: Well, that was pretty straightforward. Do you know why the example I gave `x_aux = x.append("Location")` gives `None`?

Comment: @Chris, the append function changes the list x but returns None. That's why when you assign x.append(...) to x_aux, x_aux is None because the new element is directly appended to x.